# Unity .desktop Actions internationalization and localization?

Tags: application-development, quickly, launchpad, internationalization, localization

How can we translate [Desktop Action](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_shortcuts_to_a_launcher) Names? Is it supported by quickly, launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to translate the Action's Name property just like you can elsewhere in the .desktop file.  Usually this means using _Name with the untranslated string in yourapp.deskop.in, then using whatever tool it is that applies translations to .desktop files.